# Amazon RDS swap at nearly 2GB - will it eventually crash?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My Amazon RDS instance has about 1.8GB of swap. After DB restart the swap goes up from little and then flattens around this very high level.

However, performance of the application does not seem to be impacted - Pingdom reports show no greater latency for the website.

Is there a danger that the RDS instance will crash eventually given this higher level of swap? What parameters should we look at for tuning the DB?